# How can i change the attribute of a field in Ember JS from a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In My application i have a template file with 2 fields(say name1 / name2).
Based on one parameter("preference") in the route i want to display either Recipe1 or Recipe2 on the screen.
For eg: if preference is veg, i should display Recipe1 else Recipe2.
i tried this as below but it did not work.

```
 export default Ember.Route.extend({
 beforeModel(){
 if (preference==='veg'){
     console.log("Inside Veg..");
     Ember.$("#Recipe2").attr("type","hidden");
 }
 else {
     console.log("Inside Non Veg..");
     Ember.$("#Recipe1").attr("type","hidden");
 }
```

What i see is that it goes inside the if/else loop but the ember.$ statements dont make any difference.Please help.

Comment: You should minimise the direct dom manipulation as much as possible.

Comment: @li xinyang can you elaborate a bit more on it.right now it's working as desired , but any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not write `Ember.$` inside `beforeModel` hook. that's wrong. When `beforeModel` hook called, DOM will not be ready. I prefer you to create component and pass `preference` property to component and have if check to display it in hbs

Create `my-receipe` component and include it in template.hbs

```
{{my-receipe preference=preference }}
```

my-receipe.hbs

```
{{#if isVeg}}
 <input type="text" id="Recipe1" />
{{else}}
<input type="text" id="Recipe2" />
{{/if}}
```

my-receipe.js

Create isVeg computed property which will return true if the preference is veg.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    isVeg: Ember.computed('preference', function() {
        return Ember.isEqual(this.get('preference'), 'veg');
    })
})
```

Comment: how will I pass the preference value from my route to the hbs file . In my case the preference value (veg/non veg) is derived in route based on URL parameter etc. for simplicity I had removed all that piece of code from my question.

Comment: `{{my-receipe preference=preference }}` this where we are sending preference to my-receipe.hbs

Comment: when i give like that i get undefined for 'preference' in the my-recipe.js

Comment: Inside route model hook should return `preference` or need to define it in corresponding controller. if you want to implement [query parameter](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/query-params/)

Comment: i was able to get it by writing like this `{{my-receipe preference=model.preference }}` .